# Is there a way to make an index in a dvar dependent on another dvar in Cplex?

Tags: cplex

I need to include a time aspect in my Cplex transshipment problem. Here is a part of my code where x is a binary variable that equals 1 if an order is sent over this leg from terminal i to terminal j at time t. I have 3 terminals where terminal 1 is there origin, terminal 2 is the intermediate hub and terminal 3 is the gateway.
Each order needs to be picked up at terminal 1 at pickuptime[n] and it travels on leg x for a couple of time periods that equal leadtime[1,2]. Then, it needs to proceed from terminal 2 until terminal 3 at a time t+leadtime[1,2]. However, for consolidation reasons stated in my model, it is also possible that x from terminal 2 till 3 is used at a time t that is later than t+leadtime[1,2] and is maximum equal to T:

```
dvar int+ x[terminal, terminal, order, time] in 0..1;

forall(n in order) x[1,2,n,pickuptime[n]] == 1;
forall(n in order) x[1,2,n,t] <= x[2,3,n,t+leadtime[1,2]] + x[2,3,n,t+leadtime[1,2]+1] + ... + x[2,3,n,t+leadtime[1,2]+T];
x[2,3,n,t+leadtime[1,2]] + x[2,3,n,t+leadtime[1,2]+1] + ... + x[2,3,n,t+leadtime[1,2]+T]<= 1;
```

This T depends on each order, for example for order 1:

```
x[1,2,1,t] <= x[2,3,1,t+leadtime[1,2]] + x[2,3,1,t+leadtime[1,2]+1] + x[2,3,n,t+leadtime[1,2]+2];
x[2,3,1,t+leadtime[1,2]] + x[2,3,1,t+leadtime[1,2]+1] + x[2,3,1,t+leadtime[1,2]+2]<= 1;
```

Wile for order 2:

```
x[1,2,2,t] <= x[2,3,2,t+leadtime[1,2]] + x[2,3,2,t+leadtime[1,2]+1] + x[2,3,2,t+leadtime[1,2]+2] + x[2,3,2,t+leadtime[1,2]+3];
x[2,3,2,t+leadtime[1,2]] + x[2,3,2,t+leadtime[1,2]+1] + x[2,3,2,t+leadtime[1,2]+2] + x[2,3,2,t+leadtime[1,2]+3] <= 1;
```

Is there a way to code this differently so that this is true for each order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
range T=1..10;
range Term=1..5;

int leadtime[i in Term][j in Term]=rand(10);
int t=1;

int n[1..2]=[2,3];

dvar boolean x[Term][Term][Term][T];


subject to
{
  



forall(a in 1..2)
{
  x[a,a+1,1,t] <= sum(i in 0..n[a])    x[a+1,a+2,1,t+leadtime[1,2]+i]; 
  sum(i in 0..n[a]) x[a+1,a+2,1,t+leadtime[1,2]+i] <= 1;  
}


}
```